# Firebase using only Email/Password getting a "The email address is already in use by another account." when attempting to change an email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a user trying to update their email address and She is getting a 400, "EMAIL_EXISTS"/"The email address is already in use by another account."

The application is only using Email/Password from the different auth options.  When I go to the Authentication tab and search the email address it returns no results.  Why would I get that error if there is no email address in the system?

Here is the code (Typescript / Angular / AngularFire2):

```
this.auth$.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(currentEmail, password).then(() => {

    this.auth$.auth.currentUser.updateEmail(newEmail).then((data) => {

      this.auth$.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(newEmail, password).then(() => {...
```

Comment: please, provide the code

Comment: Have you used an ID that you tried to replace before?

Comment: I have added the code I'm using.  I am able to change emails back and forth without problems on any other email address (ID) other than this one.

Comment: If I search through "authentication" in firebase by the email address it is not there.

Comment: It could be that another user had the same email but then changed it via `updateEmail`. Usually an email is sent to the original email to allow the user to revert the change. The old email would be reserved in case the original own wants to revert back to it.

Comment: @bojeil That is it!  I didn't know it reserved old emails for that specific user.  Is there any way to disable that?  Is there a time limit to it?  In this case we deleted the user manually and they wanted that email back, but as far as we can tell there is no way to get the customer that email on their account.  It's also worth noting that the email was never verified so this could cause issues if someone fat fingers someone else's email.

Comment: I don't think there is way to undo that. You can file a question via support on this: https://firebase.google.com/support/